# How can I find if my wifi card supports 802.11ac?

Tags: linux, wifi, hardware

I am unsure if my wifi card supports 802.11ac. How can I find out this information?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you run `iw list`, look for the lines specifying `VHT`.

```
    VHT Capabilities (0x038071a0):
        Max MPDU length: 3895
        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
        short GI (80 MHz)
        TX STBC
        SU Beamformee
    VHT RX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
    VHT TX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
```

This section will be totally missing if your card does not support 802.11ac.

Hence, on a card that doesn't support 802.11ac:

```
$ iw list | grep VHT
```

On a card that *does* support 802.11ac:

```
$ iw list | grep VHT
        VHT Capabilities (0x038071a0):
        VHT RX MCS set:
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
```

Comment: Why do you ask a question and answer it?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Because this question wasn't on the Stack Exchange network yet. It took me a while to find the solution, and so I'm sharing it with others. It's also encouraged to [answer your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Exchange.